# Non-homogeneous First Order PDE Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Just to be upfront, this is a homework question, but I'm just stuck on one particular part and I want to see what I'm doing wrong.

The PDE in question is the following:

$$(1+t)u_t + xu_x = e^{t}\\
u(x,0) = x$$

The way my professor has discussed solving this equation in class has been by setting a function:

$$w(t) = u(x(t),t)$$

Where x is a function of t on the characteristic curves. If you take the time derivative of w you get the following:

$$\frac{dw}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}u_x(x(t),t) + u_t(x(t),t)$$

The above mostly follows the form of the PDE given, except for the (1+t) term in front of $u_t$. If you divide both sides by (1+t), you get the correct form, but you get a seemingly impossible antiderivative:

$$w(t) = \int{\frac{e^{t}}{1+t}dt}$$

It seems highly unlikely that the professor left us a non-integrable term as part of the answer, so I probably screwed up somewhere. Additionally, is dividing both sides by (1+t) the correct course of action? It makes sense to me, but it also leads to the weird answer.

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

After dividing through by $1+t$ you see that the characteristic curves satisfy $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x}{1+t}$. This equation can be solved; you get $x=x_0(t+1)$. Then $\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{e^t}{t+1}$ so $w(t)=u(0,x_0)+\int_0^t \frac{e^s}{s+1} ds$. Finally, you need to express the answer in terms of $t$ and $x$ rather than $t$ and $x_0$. So you solve and get $x_0=\frac{x}{t+1}$. So

$$u(t,x)=u \left ( 0,\frac{x}{t+1} \right ) + \int_0^t \frac{e^s}{s+1} ds.$$

You can just leave the integral as is, at least for an analytical solution.